# Display Block not responding for my anchor link

Tags: html, css

I try to make menu for mobile display so i make a div for the menu links and want to style it so it formed a single column. so i add the `display: block;` attribute. But the links still form inline. How can i make it in a single column?

```css
.header {
  &__menu {
    background: $white;
    padding: 1.25rem;
   
    a{
        display: block;
        color:$darknavyblue;
    }
    
    }    
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <div class="header__menu">
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">Profile</a>
            <a href="">Services</a>
            <a href="">Publication</a>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
        </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy it!

```
 .header {
      &__menu {
        background: $white;
        padding: 1.25rem;
   
    a{
        color:$darknavyblue;
    }
    
    }    
}

div a{
   display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to add a break tag after each a tag:

```
<header class="header">
    <div class="header__menu">
        <a href="">Home</a><br>
        <a href="">Profile</a><br>
        <a href="">Services</a><br>
        <a href="">Publication</a><br>
        <a href="">Contact</a><br>
    </div>
```